# How to get and set Bot permissions in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've written a discord.py bot that has it's own Category and Channels assigned to it. I want to set the channels' permissions in such way, that only bot can send messages there:

```
bot_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=settings.BOT_ROLE_NAME)
for role in guild.roles:
    await category.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)
await category.set_permissions(bot_role, send_messages=True)
```

This piece of code is working, except it requires me to define the BOT_ROLE_NAME as a string, and I don't want that. I want to set the permission dynamically, without defining the role anywhere, only using the bot instance. I tried something like this:

```
for role in guild.roles:
    await category.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)
await category.set_permissions(bot.user, send_messages=True)
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to set a channel's permission using the bot instance directly?

Answer (score 0):

I feel ashamed I asked this, since the answer was super easy, and I didn't know how to figure it out for two days. That's how you get instance of the bot as a Member class:

```
for role in guild.roles:
    await category.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)
await category.set_permissions(guild.me, send_messages=True)
```